# Google+ Sign in button not working Android

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus

I'm trying to implement Google+ authentication for my Android app, but the sign in button just doesn't work.

My onClick method in SignInActivity. I also tested the same with a normal button.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Log in pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Log in pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
}
```

XML showing button properties.

```
 <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Button" />
```

When I press the normal button the toast appears just fine and authentication works, but when I press the g+ button nothing happens..

Comment: Does the toast show when you click the Google button?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need give the onClickListener to your SignIn Button. Something like that

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

      //You probably miss this line:
      this.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

      this.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   public void onClick(View view) {
     // Your stuff...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Go to [the Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/library) and enable *Google+ API*.